# Jquery Asp.net Mvc 2 resource file: TextBox onFocus/onBlur

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, resources, textbox

Hey guys, 
Was wondering which way is the best way:

The problem: Adding TextBox with a value written in it by default and when onfocus it erases and when onblur if no new data is written it reverts back to default.

My choices till now:
1- Use a cookie ?
2- Save them into variables
3- Ask stackoverflow :P

Note: 
-This is browser compatible so I need it to work on most browsers, ie6 included if possible.
-And multiple languages are used in this website and it access resources files for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- Use a cookie

Can't see any relevance.

> 2- Save them into variables

Can't see any relevance.

> 3- Ask stackoverflow

You may take a look at the [jquery watermark plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/).

Comment: awesome, this is my first try with jquery, Thanks. Also, are you positive this would work in ie6 ?
I'll test it in a bit. thanks a lot.